# How do I change the font of a parameter to a function in elisp / latex-mode

Tags: emacs, latex, font-lock

I know I can add keywords to `font-lock-mode` using `font-lock-add-keywords`.

However, I would like to change the font color of the parameter to a latex function.

In Latex mode, if I write:

```
\cite{Somebody1999}
```

then `Somebody1999` will be highlighted in `font-lock-constant-face`.

However, if I write:

```
\citeasnoun{Somebody1999}
```

Then `citeasnoun` is correctly colored as `font-lock-keyword-face`, but `Somebody1999` is colored as "default". Presumably the mode recognizes that a backslash makes this a function, but it does not recognize `citeasnoun` as a keyword.

I've tried adding `citeasnoun` to the list of `font-lock-keyword-face`, but this did not have an effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the default highlighting used latex-mode does not let you customize the list of "cite-like" commands.
But you can try something like

```
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (font-lock-add-keywords nil
              '(("\\\\citeasnoun{\\([^}\n]+\\)" (1 'font-lock-constant-face))))))
```

If you use AUCTeX, then you'll probably have to change the above code to use `LaTeX-mode-hook` instead.